# Center HREF in table

Tags: html, css

Hey guys its me again with another easy one.  I want to center the text for the Href's inside these tables below:  Should I put a style:center on the  tag?

```
    <table class="link_table" style="display: inline;margin: 0 40px">             
        <tr>             
        <td>                 
        <a href="show.hotpartslist">Proceed</a>              
        </td> 
        </table>
        <table class="link_table" style="display: inline;margin: 0 40px">       
        <td>                 
        <a href="show.home">Cancel</a>                 
        </td>                 
        </tr>         
        </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use text-align: center on your table cell.

Like this:

```
<table style="width: 300px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="">somelink</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: didnt seem to work tried: <table class="link_table" style="text-align: center;display: inline;margin: 0 40px">

Comment: @DocHoliday: I've added a piece of example code that works just fine. Maybe it's somewhere else in your styling.

Answer (score 0):

beyond the obvious that you shouldn't use tables to format layout --- wrap your tables in a Div and set text-align: center;  also you are missing a closing `</tr>` and an opening `<tr>` in the code you typed not sure if that is the case on your page as well.

```
<div style='text-align: center;'>
 <table><tr><td>Proceed</td></tr></table>
 <table><tr><td>Cancel</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

a better way to handle this is to do soemthing like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><div class='link_table'>Proceed</div></td>
  <td><div class='link_table'>Cancel</div></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

better yet

```
<div id="buttonWrapper">
 <div id='proceed' class='link_table'>Proceed</div>
 <div id='cancel' class='link_table'>Cancel</div>
</div>


<style type='text/css'>
 #buttonWrapper { display: table; margin: auto; }
 #proceed { float: left; margin-right: 50px; }
</style>
```